# What is MapRoute namespaces parameter for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

ASP.NET MVC's MapRoute method has a parameter named `namespaces`. From looking in the code, I see that this parameter is saved in the `Route` object in `DataTokens["Namespaces"]`.

It seems to me that it has some meaning... anyone knows what is it for?

Answer (score 0):

In MVC4 'namespaces' parameters is no longer a secret, it optionally provides namespaces to search for controllers. It can be used with `Areas`, for example.

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492682(v=vs.108).aspx

I think this question should be deleted as outdated.